# full disk encryption boot gui gone

Tags: boot, encryption, gui

I have installed my Ubuntu system with full disk encryption.

After installing updates, the GUI that you type the password will not show, just a command line interface that keeps ticking information about my computer and can get a little annoying when I think I mistyped my paraphrase.

How can I get that GUI back?

As requested in the comments, my Grub settings:

```
⟫ grep -F GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="drm.debug=0xe plymouth:debug"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Did you change some Grub settings? This is probably due to a change in the kernel boot parameter options. Please [edit] your question to provide the output of the following command and if it shows what I think it will, then I'm happy to provide an answer. `grep -F GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX /etc/default/grub`

Comment: @gertvdijk Output added

Comment: Did you put the plymouth debug option there deliberately? If not, remove it (so that the line becomes `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="drm.debug=0xe"`), then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot to see if that works. If it does, I'll post it as an answer, if not, edit your question to include that removing didn't bring back the GUI. And if you know, please share how that setting got there, becuase it didn't get there by itself.

Comment: that did not fix my issue, however, the boot is much cleaner now.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was mistaken about the exact contents. I looked at my own config again. add this: `quiet splash` at the same spot as you removed the plymouth stuff and re-run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: that does not fix my problem

Comment: You probably installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers. At least that was the issue in my case where I just  get a black screen to type in my password. But sadly I didn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be an upstream issue. Linux Mint 17.2 (not 17.1) and Debian 8 are showing a CLI instead of GUI to decrypt system.